# Removing spacing in pgf-umlsd

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is a part of my code:

```
\documentclass{report}                                                          
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}                                        
\usepackage{graphicx}                                                           
\usepackage{tikz}                                                               
\usepackage{pdflscape}                                                          
\usepackage[underline=true,rounded corners=false]{pgf-umlsd}                    

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}                                                 

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}                                                     

\begin{document}                                                                
\chapter{Registering Customers}                                                 
\begin{center}                                                                  
    \begin{figure}                                                              
        \begin{sequencediagram}
            \newthread{cust}{:Customer}                                         
            \newinst[2]{reg}{:CustomerInterface}                                
            \newinst[1]{db}{:Database}                                          

            \begin{call}{cust}{register(un,pw,...)}{reg}{return}              
                \begin{call}{reg}{reg(un,pw,...)}{db}{return}                 
                \end{call}                                    
            \end{call}                                                          
        \end{sequencediagram}                                                   
    \end{figure}                                                                
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

The spacing between title and graph is too large, how can I reduce it to something reasonable? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things needed fixing:

1) centering goes inside the figure, not outside;

2) `\centering` rather than the `center` environment is preferable inside another environment (in this case, inside `figure`), lest it introduce additional, unwanted, vertical space; and

3) use `[ht]` as the figure option to place the figure "here", if possible.

```
\documentclass{report}                                                          
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}                                        
\usepackage{graphicx}                                                           
\usepackage{tikz}                                                               
\usepackage{pdflscape}                                                          
\usepackage[underline=true,rounded corners=false]{pgf-umlsd}                    

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}                                                 

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}                                                     

\begin{document}                                                                
\chapter{Registering Customers}                                                 

    \begin{figure}[ht]
       \centering                                                             
        \begin{sequencediagram}
            \newthread{cust}{:Customer}                                         
            \newinst[2]{reg}{:CustomerInterface}                                
            \newinst[1]{db}{:Database}                                          

            \begin{call}{cust}{register(un,pw,...)}{reg}{return}              
                \begin{call}{reg}{reg(un,pw,...)}{db}{return}                 
                \end{call}                                    
            \end{call}                                                          
        \end{sequencediagram}                                                   
    \end{figure}                                                                

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir! Works well. By the way, which doc should I look up for [ht] parameter?

Comment: @hlx98007 That would be p.176 of the LaTeX User Guide and Reference Manual, by Leslie Lamport.  The options are `h` (here), `t` (top), `b` (bottom), and `p` (page by itself).  They can be specified in multiplicity, to indicate the priority , e.g., `[htbp]`.  The use of `[h]` by itself will produce a warning, in that it wants a backup location, if it can't place the figure "here".  These same options are used for many if not all floating environments.