# Code for a exchange protocol

Tags: code

Hi I want to insert a exchange protocol in my lab report. The protocol looks something like this : [image]

How can I write such protocol in latex?

Comment: You can use tikz and pgf packages, see, choose and modify one example from here http://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/

Comment: [`msc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/msc) (Message Sequence Protocol) package can help you. Here you have an example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54390/1952

Comment: The `pgf-umlsd` package may also be what you are looking for.  Here is question that uses it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161689/removing-spacing-in-pgf-umlsd

Answer (score 2):

This is really quick and dirty, put illustrates hoot set such a picture with TikZ. Note that I coded all the positions manually -- which is a bit cumbersome if you have to draw multiple diagram with different node configurations etc. The right way would probably to use the `positioning` library or something else to let TikZ choose the position automatically. You may also check out [the answer to this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54390/1952), which [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi) linked to in their comment above.

However, here is a code that produces a TikZ picture similar to the one you posted. (Again, there certainly are much more elegant ways to achieve the same or a better result.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node [draw] (I) at (0,5) {Init. $I$};
     \node [draw] (R) at (8,5) {Resp. $R$};
     \node [draw] (K1) at (0,2) {$k_i, k_r, k_1, k_2 = \textsf{kdf}(g^{x,y},n_i|n_r)$};
     \node [draw] (K2) at (8,2) {$k_i, k_r, k_1, k_2 = \textsf{kdf}(g^{x,y},n_i|n_r)$};
     \node  at (4,4.5) {$\texttt{SA\_INIT}(\textcolor{red}{\texttt{SA}_i}|g^x,|n_i|\textcolor{red}{\textit{info}_i})$};
     \node  at (4,4) {$\texttt{SA\_INIT}(\textcolor{red}{ck})$};
    \node  at (4,3.5) {$m_1 = \texttt{SA\_INIT}(\textcolor{red}{ck}|\textcolor{red}{\texttt{SA}_i}|g^x|n_i|\textcolor{red}{\textit{info}_i})$};
     \node  at (4,3.0) {$m_2 = \texttt{SA\_INIT}(\textcolor{red}{\texttt{SA}_r}|g^y|n_r|\textcolor{red}{\textit{info}_r})$};
     \node at (4,1.0) {$[\texttt{AUTH}(\textcolor{red}{\texttt{ID}_i}|\textsf{sign}(sk_I,\textsc{hash}(m_I|n_r|\textsf{mac}(k_i,\texttt{ID}_i))))]^{k_1}$};
     \node at (4,0.5) {$[\texttt{AUTH}(\textcolor{red}{\texttt{ID}_r}|\textsf{sign}(sk_R,\textsc{hash}(m_R|n_i|\textsf{mac}(k_r,\texttt{ID}_i))))]^{k_2}$};
     \draw (I) -- (K1);
     \draw (R) -- (K2);
     \draw [->] (0,4.25) -- (8,4.25);
     \draw [<-] (0,3.75) -- (8,3.75);
     \draw [->] (0,3.25) -- (8,3.25);
     \draw [<-] (0,2.75) -- (8,2.75);
     \draw [->] (0,0.75) -- (8,0.75);
    \draw [<-] (0,0.25) -- (8,0.25);
    \node (B1) [fill,color=black,text width=1.2cm] at (0,-0.5) {};
    \node (B2) [fill,color=black,text width=1.2cm] at (8,-0.5) {}; 
    \draw (K1) -- (B1);
    \draw (K2) -- (B2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your example with [`msc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/msc). Compile it with `xelatex` because `msc` uses `pstricks`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\instdist}{8.5cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{3cm}
\begin{msc}{}
\declinst{I}{}{Init. $I$}
\declinst{R}{}{Resp. $R$}
\mess{$\texttt{SA\_INIT}(\textcolor{red}{\texttt{SA}_i}|g^x,|n_i|\textcolor{red}{\textit{info}_i})$}{I}{R}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\texttt{SA\_INIT}(\textcolor{red}{ck})$}{R}{I}
\nextlevel
\mess{$m_1 = \texttt{SA\_INIT}(\textcolor{red}{ck}|\textcolor{red}{\texttt{SA}_i}|g^x|n_i|\textcolor{red}{\textit{info}_i})$}{I}{R}
\nextlevel
\mess{$m_2 = \texttt{SA\_INIT}(\textcolor{red}{\texttt{SA}_r}|g^y|n_r|\textcolor{red}{\textit{info}_r})$}{R}{I}
\nextlevel
\action*{\small{$k_i, k_r, k_1, k_2 = \textsf{kdf}(g^{x,y},n_i|n_r)$}}{I}
\action*{\small{$k_i, k_r, k_1, k_2 = \textsf{kdf}(g^{x,y},n_i|n_r)$}}{R}
\nextlevel[3]
\mess{$[\texttt{AUTH}(\textcolor{red}{\texttt{ID}_i}|\textsf{sign}(sk_I,\textsc{hash}(m_I|n_r|\textsf{mac}(k_i,\texttt{ID}_i))))]^{k_1}$}{I}{R}
\nextlevel
\mess{$[\texttt{AUTH}(\textcolor{red}{\texttt{ID}_r}|\textsf{sign}(sk_R,\textsc{hash}(m_R|n_i|\textsf{mac}(k_r,\texttt{ID}_i))))]^{k_2}$}{R}{I}
\end{msc}
\end{document}
```

[image]