# Exchanging conversations

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I want to create this message exchange structure. I need that structure for school
[image]

I can only do the the above top message. I don't know how create The below part

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[block1/.style={draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum 
 height=1.8cm},
 block2/.style={draw, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=.8cm},
 >=Stealth]
 \node[block1] (b1) {Include pic?};
 \node[block1, right=5cm of b1] (b2) {2};

 \draw[->] ([yshift=3mm]b1.east)--node[above] {hello} ([yshift=3mm]b2.west);
 ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks for your help !!!! :)

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Is doing this in LaTeX homework? Or is the assignment on something else and you just want to use LaTeX? If the latter, you could just draw it in Inkscape or something and include the PDF. Or you could export Ti*k*Z code for inclusion in your document.

Comment: Yes, create this figure in latex for include the code(of figure) in my latex document :)

Comment: Aren't there packages for this sort of thing, like `pgf-umlsd`?  e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174207/adding-content-on-sequence-diagram-tikz-uml-pgf-umlsd

Comment: What I mean is, you can draw it in Inkscape and export the Ti*k*Z code. Or you can work through one of the tutorials in the manual, if you want to learn the basics. This is just some lines, boxes and circles, after all. You don't say what you're having trouble with.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes 
Thank you !!! It looks great. I will work it :)

Comment: You could also use [`msc`](http://satoss.uni.lu/software/mscpackage/) package. Some examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54390/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302962/1952.